# How can i stop html downsizing?

Tags: html, css

You know how on google you can stop the html from getting smaller after a certain screen width? Like the google search page will only downsize so much before it just stops. Is there anyway i can do this on my html? I'm new to bootstrap.

Here is my pen --> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/xpEqWX

```
.
```

I saw this codepen in which the text got smaller depending on screen size. How did they do this? --> https://codepen.io/jpamental/pen/QadmNv

Comment: Are you looking for something like @media rule? Maybe this helps: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
It helps you to define different sizing rule for different screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use media queries to control specific layout preferences at certain screen sizes. Bootstrap tends toward fully mobile-responsive layouts. You can customize your layout at any given threshold by adding these media queries to your CSS file which will override the default bootstrap behaviour.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px)
```

Just a basic example for reference. You will find this helpful; there are many to choose from.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp -- Link to W3Schools Media Query tutorial.

Comment: I added it on and it still goes down and doesn't stop downsizing. Is there anything i have to change when it reaches that certain dimensions?

Comment: Consistent resizing usually occurs because you have a width property set to 100% throughout the changing tiers. Explicitly define the width in each media query. 

As a less reluctant, bare bones approach, you could also use a [non-responsive Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/non-responsive/) template.

Comment: body {
    min-width: 520px;
} --> was the answer